# Корень слова "прийти"

Tags: словообразование

Как найти корень слова "прийти"?

Answer (score 1):

В слове "прийти" корень "-и", поскольку именно эта часть остается постоянной при любых изменениях слова.

Comment: Не поэтому, разумеется, но потому что это верно исторически.

Answer (score 1):

Корень й, при - приставка, ти - суффикс.